# Find corresponding id of the selected value using Radio Button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, forms

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1h5cxx) 
I am trying to find the id associated with the name I select using the radio button. Any help?

```
<form #filterForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addFilter(filterForm)" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="border: 1px solid red">
            <div *ngFor="let x of countryArray">
                <label for="{{x.name}}"> {{x.name}} </label>
                <input type="radio" id="{{x.name}}" value="{{x.name}}" name="name" [(ngModel)]='selected'>
                            </div>
            </div>
            <hr />

            <button type="submit">SAVE</button>

        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `console.log(this.countryArray.filter(e => e.id === 1));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 0):

try to declare a property and set the value on model change event

```html
<div *ngFor="let x of countryArray">
    <label for="{{x.name}}"> {{x.name}} </label>
    <input type="radio" id="{{x.name}}" value="{{x.name}}" name="name" 
       ngModel (ngModelChange)="selectedValue = x">
  </div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrt1vy)